# How do I fix a Thread Leak in a JSF application?

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have an ApplicationScoped bean that fires up a separate Thread to do some background work.  The Thread has a method for cleanly terminating it called **terminate()**.  If not terminated via that method it runs in an infinite loop, and sleeps for a while if it finds it has nothing to do.

The thing is I am in development mode (Netbeans -> Maven) and each time I recompile the application, the Maven plug-in un-deploys and redeploys the application (most conveniently I must say) but the background Thread from the *last* deployment hangs around.  It eventually terminates with an Exception because it wakes up from its sleep and tries to access a JPA EntityManager that isn't there anymore.

I would prefer to automatically call the **terminate()** method when the application is stopped.  Is there some way to implement a listener that will do that at the JSF 2.0 specification level?  If not, how about at the Servlet level?

This is using GlassFish 3.1.1.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499534/applicationscope-bean-that-uses-a-timertask-sheduler-good-or-bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `@PreDestroy` method to you bean which will run when your application is undeployed or stopped and it can stop the background thread, like this:

```
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean
public class AppBean {

    public AppBean() {
        System.out.println("new AppBean()");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestory() {
        // call thread.terminate() here
        System.out.println("preDestory");
    }
}
```

Comment: My application scoped bean is managed by CDI -- is it expected to process the **PreDestroy** annotation?

Comment: Yes, I think so. "The Java EE `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` callbacks are also supported for all managed beans.", from: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e4657