# Update faces-config.xml in memory at runtime

Tags: jsf, xpages

When a JSF/XPages application starts it reads the faces-config.xml for managed beans, validators etc. Can I manipulate the loaded configuration at runtime? e.g. dynamically add a validator to ensure my custom code will run.

I'm not trying to change the xml file at runtime, but the memory representation after it gets loaded.

XPages uses a JSF 1.x runtime,so JSF 2.0 constructs might not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a lot of JSF artifacts which are normally configured in `faces-config.xml`  by among others the [`Application` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html) as well.

```
Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
application.addValidator("fooValidator", "com.example.FooValidator");
// ...
```

You could do the job in an eagerly initialized application scoped managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Config {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Will it work with Domino implementation of JSF in XPages engine? AFAIK http://stackoverflow.com/a/9992766/206265

Comment: Thx for the info. My bad: I didn't mention JSF 1.x, so no annotations. But the addValidator() will probably work