# FacesContextListener implementation

Tags: xpages, faces-config

In an attempt to implement the [FacesContextListener](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/com/ibm/xsp/event/FacesContextListener.html), which seems to be [the ideal place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10001321) for the current challenge we are facing, I still struggle with its implementation. Attempts to declare it in the faces-config.xml or a construction similar to the [ApplicationListener](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=733) failed (as I probably reference things wrong (except for the class itself of course)).

Can someone provide directions / a short example regarding the implementation of the [FacesContextListener](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/com/ibm/xsp/event/FacesContextListener.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Java class which implements FacesContextListener interface.

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import com.ibm.xsp.event.FacesContextListener;

public class MyFacesContextListener implements FacesContextListener {

    public void beforeContextReleased(FacesContext fc) {
        System.out.println("beforeContextReleased");
    }

    public void beforeRenderingPhase(FacesContext fc) {
        System.out.println("beforeRenderingPhase"); 
    }

}
```

Now, add an instance of the class to your XPage:

```
importPackage( ch.hasselba.xpages )
var fcl = new ch.hasselba.xpages.MyFacesContextListener();
facesContext.addRequestListener( fcl );
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**
Here is a Java implementation with an anonymous Listener:

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import com.ibm.xsp.context.FacesContextExImpl;
import com.ibm.xsp.event.FacesContextListener;

public class MyObject {

    private transient FacesContextListener mFCListener;

    public MyObject() {
            mFCListener = new FacesContextListener() {

            public void beforeContextReleased(FacesContext fc) {
                System.out.println("Before Releasing.");
            }

            public void beforeRenderingPhase(FacesContext fc) {
                System.out.println("Before Rendering.");
            }
     };

     FacesContextExImpl fc = (FacesContextExImpl) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     fc.addRequestListener( this.mFCListener );
 }
}
```