# Best way to create @ApplicationScoped scheduled process

Tags: java, jsf, scheduled-tasks

I need to try to create and send emails within a JSF application, but if an exception is encountered, store the email in a database table and periodically check this table (say every 10 mins) to try and send the email again.

I have the email piece working, but want to understand the basic techniques I should try to create the polling service.  I was thinking perhaps an `@ApplicationScoped` bean, but am not sure of how to create a process which runs in the bean every 10 mins or so.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ApplicationScope bean that uses a TimerTask (sheduler), good or bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499534/applicationscope-bean-that-uses-a-timertask-sheduler-good-or-bad)

Comment: You can create `java.util.Timer` in init method annotated with `@PostConstruct`

Comment: @GKlimov: no, no, NO! Read the duplicate link for the reasons why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify exactly what environment you are working in, expect JSF. What you want, however, sounds like some kind of scheduled timer. There are several ways to achieve this:

[Java EE Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) is probably the easiest way to go if you have access to the full Java EE stack. A simple annotation, like `@Schedule(minute="*/10", hour="*")` on a method in a `@Stateless` bean would create a timer that executes every tenth minute.

Another very frequently used library for this is [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), which can do the same thing. If *Spring* is being used, I would recommend using Quartz through Spring. See the [official documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) for help on how to set it up.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Sorry I am not using a JEE container, but just plain old Tomcat.  I read somewhere to avoid using Timer due to its threading model i.e. if an exception gets thrown it kills the Timer.

Comment: Well, some kind of timer is needed here. And the statement that the timer would get killed if an exception is thrown, I don't think that is true at all. For EJB Java EE timers I'm pretty sure that a rollback would occur. Since you are using Tomcat I would recommend using Quartz, it is really more or less the standard library to use for timers. I'm also pretty sure it can handle exceptions in an appropriate way.

Comment: Do I, or should I be using any Spring config with quartz?

Comment: Yeah. Typically Spring has support for anything you want. :) I updated my answer with a link to the Spring documentation. You should have specified in your question that you are using Spring. In your case I would use Quartz and Spring together, as described in the link.