# ApplicationScoped ManagedBean as Timer / Scheduler, shorter scope issue

Tags: java, jsf, scope, lookup, pojo

I am writing a simple web application that must run on different (probably old) Java application servers. Therefore I can't use the latest JEE goodies :) please consider this before answering.

The project uses JSF 2.0

```
jsf-myfaces.version2.1.7 
jsf-mojarra.version 2.1.7
javax.servlet 1.2
```

I have a managed bean that processes the GUI requests, creates objects and uses another managed bean to persist these objects.

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "HOSTS")
public class Host implements Comparable<Host>{
//...
}

@ManagedBean(name = "HostController")
@RequestScoped
public class HostController {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource 
    private UserTransaction utx;

    public void merge(Host host) {
        //....
    }

//....
}
```

So far everything works as planned.

The next requirement is a batch job which runs every 24 hours. As supposed here: [Spawning threads in a JSF managed bean for scheduled tasks using a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499534/applicationscope-bean-that-uses-a-timertask-sheduler-good-or-bad) I created a managed bean (ApplicationScoped) and tried to use it as a timer. (I can't use the other solutions because the necessary libs are probably not provided by the target AS)

The batch job is supposed to grab all Host objects from the database and run some tasks on them. The result of those tasks are new objects that need to be stored in the database. I already have a requestScoped managed bean similar to HostController that can do the DB operations.

As supposed in the other Thread the class that implements the batch-job is not a bean.
(link above: SomeDailyJob) 
Therefore I can't get an instance of my HostController class. (At least I don't know how to do that).
Note: javax.enterprise.inject.spi is not available  - if you think this package would help I need to know the oldest versions of JBoss and WebLogic that provide it.

The application scoped bean is not able to access the HostController, too. (shorter scope)

Comment: Whats wrong with a `@Singleton` solution?

Comment: As far as I know @Singleton is part of Java EE6 but not supported by Java EE5.