# FacesContext resolves to null in ApplicationScoped bean

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, servlet-filters, jsf-2.2, facescontext

I have a filter: `UserSessionFilter.java`, that I use to handle user sessions and a `ApplicationScoped` bean: `Config.java` that primarily gives me access to a `DAO factory`.

**Config.java**

```
@ManagedBean (eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Config implements Serializable {...
```

The filter calls a method in `Config` to get a `DAOFactory` object:

**Filter method**

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    daoFactory = Config.getInstance().getDAOFactory();
}
```

**Config method**

```
public static Config getInstance() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return (Config) facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(
                 facesContext, "#{config}", Config.class);
}
```

My problem is that the `facesContext` gets set to `null`. This problem started occurring after switch from `Mojarra` to `MyFaces`, although it seems weird that that would cause it.

Answer (score 0):

FacesContext cannot be used inside the Filter. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803160/facescontext-null) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045242/how-do-i-retrieve-the-facescontext-within-a-filter) answers. Reason:

> The FacesContext is created by the FacesServlet and thus only available within any Java code which is processed by the FacesServlet, which covers all JSF artifacts, such as managed beans and phase listeners

Comment: Yes. But this is happening inside the `ApplicationScoped and eager` bean called `Config` and does not give an error when using `Mojarra`, only when using `MyFaces`

Comment: I had exact the same behavior in Mojarra too.

Comment: If you need the instance of Config, then you can try `request.getSession().getAttribute("config")` inside `doFilter` method of your filter class in case if Config already exist in session.