# Local Thread linked with RequestScope

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, weld

I have a web service built with VRaptor that uses CDI (weld 2.1.2.Final). I need to parallelize some of the processing made by the server (statistical analysis of industrial alarms). I'm doing that using a ExecutorService and Callable instances, unfortunately I need one Request Scoped dependence inside my Threads. Because of that dependence I'm facing this error:

```
WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

Is there a way to link the Threads to the Request where they were created using CDI?

*I know that I shouldn't be opening threads in the server, but this is the currently most viable option

Comment: What container are you running on?

Comment: I'm running on Tomact 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as constructor argument of the callable.

```
public class YourTask implements Callable<String> {

    private YourData data;

    public YourTask(YourData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() {
        // Just use data.
    }

}
```

```
@Inject
private YourRequestScopedBean bean;

public void submit() {
    YourTask task = new YourTask(bean.getData());
    // ...
}
```

Note: do not pass the bean itself as it's basically a [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651008/field-getobj-returns-all-nulls-on-injected-cdi-managed-beans-while-manually-i/29672591#29672591) whose instance doesn't exist in other thread.

#### See also:

- [FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() returns null in Runnable class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803160/facescontext-getcurrentinstance-returns-null-in-runnable-class/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, manually managing threads in a Java EE container, even though when done via a properly programmed `ExecutorService`, is frowned upon. It indicates you aren't aware of possibilities of Java EE's EJB scheduling and timer APIs. You may find the examples in this answer useful: [Is it safe to start a new thread in a JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149919/is-it-safe-to-start-a-new-thread-in-a-jsf-managed-bean)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that manually managing threads in a Java EE is frowned upon. But in this case I need (or there is another solution that I can't see), in the system I'm developing we may need to consult 20+ database that may contain millions of data (It's a industrial alarm analysis system), I have to parallelize the process. Maybe I should make a microservice and segrete part of the process from my server, but that solution is too far away and would consume too much time.

Comment: "Note: do not pass the bean itself as it's basically a proxy whose instance doesn't exist in other thread" I didn't know that (I still got a lot to learn), there is no way to pass the bean itself? And once again, thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm also controlling the number of threads one user can spawn, and the total number of threads that can spawn