# Is it possible to create a new thread in a @RequestScope bean

Tags: java, asynchronous, jboss, wildfly, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a Service class which is annotated with @RequestScope, the problem is that there is one method which takes too long time to proceed and I'm wondering if it's possible to create new Thread in which part of the code will be executed.

I've tried using ManagedExecutorService, CompletableFuture.runAsync(())
and a simple Thread, but none of them seems to work?

```java
@RequestScoped
public class OfferService
```

And the method:

```java
  public List<DTO> createLocation(List<DTO> locationAdressDTOS) {
        List<DTO> lokationLookupList ;

        locationLookupList = offerDao.createMarktlokation(DTOS.get(0).getOfferNo(), DTOS);

        DTOS.forEach(malo -> {
            if (BooleanUtils.isTrue(malo.isShouldUploadHistoricalData()) && malo.getProcessId() != null) {
                callHistoricalDataUpload(malo.getOfferNo(), malo.getProcessId());
            }
        });
        return lokationLookupList;
    }
```

And I want the if part to be run asynchronous? //

```java
 callHistoricalDataUpload(malo.getOfferNo(), malo.getProcessId());
```

I believe the reason that it's not working is because the class is annotated with @RequestScope and after it returns the response is being destroyed and it's context too?
When I try to simply create a new Thread:

```java
2019-05-23 14:45:31,934 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-225) Exception in thread "Thread-225" org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

What I have tried:

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                this.uploadHistoricalData(offerNo, processId);
            } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException | ParseException e) {
                logger.severe(e.getMessage());
            }
        });


        managedExecutorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                this.uploadHistoricalData(offerNo, processId);

            } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException | ParseException e) {
                logger.severe(e.getMessage());
            }
        });


        new Thread((() -> {
            try {

                this.uploadHistoricalData(offerNo, processId);

            } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException | ParseException e) {
                logger.severe(e.getMessage());
            }
        })).start();
```

None of that worked

Comment: You can create a simple thread to perform certain operation.

Comment: Could you show us the code that generated the error? It seems like it's missing the thread creation you mentioned.

Comment: @ÁlexSantanaFogaça I have just edited the post you can take a look :)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your problem is that same as this [other question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389159/weld-001303-no-active-contexts-for-scope-type-javax-enterprise-context-requests).

> It's because the request is tied to the server thread processing the request. When you switch threads, there is no longer access to that request context.

You might not need the @RequestScoped annotation.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remove this annotation. Is it possible to propagate the request context to the new thread?

Comment: It is. You may collect the data you need before and then use it on your asynchronous call.

Comment: There is a solution available on this [thread about propagating the request scope to an asynchronous task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732089/how-to-enable-request-scope-in-async-task-executor), but it's a bit much depending on your situation.

Comment: Thats a spring dependent solution

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've found this [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815608/local-thread-linked-with-requestscope) and it seems concise.

Comment: Thanks!  that looks viable, I will give it a try and reply if it works!  :)